# cannot unset properties with ant-contrib when loading two extenal property files

Tags: apache, ant, build-automation, ant-contrib

So ... I have build.xml that loads property file from basedir.

Then, as the target I perform the following:

```
<var name="Var1" value="<property_from_**first**_loaded_property_file>" />
<var name="<property_from_**first**_loaded_property_file>" unset="true"/>
<property file="../<other directory>/<**second**_property_file>.properties" />
<var name="Var2" value="<property_from_**second**_loaded_property_file>"/>
```

The ceavat here is that both   has ***same*** property name. It cannot be changed.

So, in the end, I should get the property like:

```
Var1=<property_from_**first**_loaded_property_file>

Var2=<property_from_**second**_loaded_property_file>
```

But instead - 
I am getting signs that property (Var1) from first properties file is not unset and then filled with new value from second properties file. The thing that ant-contribs unset should deal with :/ ... something like:

```
Var1 = Var2
```

Why I am not getting the expected result?

Comment: from the echoed results I am getting signs that value from pirts properties file is not unset and then filled with new value from second properties file. The thing that ant-contribs unset should deal with :/

Comment: what do the property files contain

Comment: identical property names with different values (Var1=1 in first propfile ; Var1=2 in second propfile). This would be most elegant solution for my task, if only it would work as supposed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that even though you're loading the variable into an antcontrib `var`, it's still an ant `property` first, thus immutable.

I know you can't change the property files, but what kind of freedom do you have with the script itself? You can try to leverage the scoping rules and the `antcallback` task to scope where the variables get loaded.

For example, the following achieves - albeit somewhat messily - what I think you're after:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="Test" basedir=".">

    <path id="ant.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}">
            <include name="ant-contrib_AP.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" classpathref="ant.classpath"/>

    <target name="test">

        <antcallback target="load-more-prop" return="Var2"/>

        <loadproperties>
            <file file="prop1.properties"/>
        </loadproperties>

        <property name="Var1" value="${var}" />

        <echo>${Var1}</echo>
        <echo>${Var2}</echo>

    </target>

    <target name="load-more-prop">

        <loadproperties>
            <file file="prop2.properties"/>
        </loadproperties>

        <property name="Var2" value="${var}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

In my console I see:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\mfelzani\workspace-junk\junk\build.xml
test:
load-more-prop:
 [echo] 7
 [echo] 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 905 milliseconds
```

Which matches the values i set in prop1.properties and prop2.properties, respectively, for the var property.

Comment: awesome and good luck. also, don't be afraid to call loadproperties for prop2 in your "test"-equivalent target after you load prop1 just so that you can have that aggregate of properties available to you. also, sorry about the inconsistent loadproperties/property task usage. victim of copy/paste there. i'll fix that now to be consistent.

Comment: if it does work, i'd love it if you marked this answer as "the answer" ... it'd be my first one! thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't unset the value.

```
WRONG: <var name="<property_from_**first**_loaded_property_file>" unset="true"/>
```

You have to unset the variable

```
CORRECT: <var name="Var1" unset="true"/>
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but ... umm ... but if I am specifying value using ${variable_form_first_loaded_properties_file} ? I would be unable to store a new value into the same property name later ...

Comment: @HX_unbanned if it is a variable it might work, but I'm not sure

Comment: Well, - it do not work :( ... Maybe there is other way to compare properties with same name in two diffrent propfiles?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to overwrite some existing property or userproperty (those properties defined via ant commandline
 parameter -Dkey=value), you might use [**Ant Plugin Flaka**](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) as alternative for antcontrib.
With Flaka's let task you either create a new property or overwrite any existing property straightforward :

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">

 <property name="foo" value="bar"/>

 <!-- create new property -->
 <fl:let>foo := 'baar'</fl:let>
 <echo>$${foo} => ${foo}</echo>

 <!--
  overwrite existing property
  notice the double '::' in foo ::= 'baz'
 -->
 <fl:let>foo ::= 'baz'</fl:let>
 <echo>$${foo} => ${foo}</echo>

</project>
```